# How to fix position of one element in a flexbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I have 2 boxes: Panel and Sidebar, in a flexbox, with `flex-direction: row` and `justify-content: space-between` I am able to horizontally align them side by side with a gap in the middle.

Now I'd like to fix the right Sidebar position, i.e. when scrolling down, the Sidebar should always stay on top of the screen, regardless of the location of Panel. How can I do it with CSS?

Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-saha-zgmnw

Code here:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";
import Panel from "./Panel";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Panel />
      <Sidebar />
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.scss:

```
.App {
  width: 1100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Panel.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Panel.scss";

const Panel = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="panel">The main panel</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Panel;
```

Sidebar.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Sidebar.scss";

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="sidebar">The sidebar</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: use absolute or sticky

Comment: @DCR would that work with parental `display: flex`?

Comment: display:flex; position:relative;  then in your element you want to place use position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

I modified your siderbar css.
I used position fixed as this will make the sidebar fixed in the viewport so as you scroll it will remain static.

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;            /* add this */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px black solid;
  left: 906px                /* add this */
}
```

This produces the desired effect. Tested and works. Apologies, I have updated my answer.

Comment: The sidebar does stick to the top of the screen, but `right: 0px` makes it stick to right side of the page, which isn't the same as original design

Answer (score 0):

add this css to .sidebar

```
position:fixed;
right: 10px;
```

also, you can add:

```
top: -- px
```

if you have Navbar.